# Can't log in normally, have desktop and user profile issues in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

For some reason my computer has some problem(s) that I don't know the origin of, nor how to solve them.

I've had these problems for three days and have tried to fix them but to no avail.

Here are the issues:

When I try to log in on my computer I get a message that says:

> The group policy client service failed the logon, Access denied.

Then it logs off and returns to the profile selection screen.

After that I tried to log in via "Safe mode" and it work without getting the message. However here comes my next problem (these problems are only in Safe Mode since I can't log in normally):

When I log in via Safe mode, my desktop icons are gone and my background is black. Also some of my programs in my Start Menu are gone.

On my "computer" (windows+E or via the Start Menu) some folders on the left panel are gone. When I right click and click on " show all folders" nothing happens:

[image]

Things that I've tried:

1. Chkdsk (doesn't find any problems)
2. SFC/scannow (found some corrupted files, don't know what to do after that - it only said that some files couldn't be repaired and that the repair will take place after rebooting. I did restart my computer but the problem is still there)
3. System restore (didn't help at all)

My other problem is (also in Safe Mode):

In my profile: `c:/users/eric` (personal profile) I only have the following folders:

```
Appdata
Contacts
Desktop
ntuser
```

(I can't find my documents, videos, pictures etc)

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

What is causing this problem? Is it the user profile or something else?

I will not try to fix my computer now, in case I do something wrong and all my files are deleted (videos, pictures, documents and files that were on my desktop). Does anyone have a safe solution?

Comment: Where does HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ point to? Each key will be named by SID so you will have to find the user name by looking at the subkeys. BTW your full name is in those screen shots.

Comment: the specific key you are looking for under your SID is: ProfileImagePath

Comment: Your Windows installation is corrupt.  You should backup your important documents and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think they know how to back up the data when they cannot log in, you might post this as an answer and give details on How to do as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Eric, you files should still there, they just don't show up when logging into safe mode, your files can be found in the

Vista W7

> C:\Users\ [your user name]

XP

> C:\Documents and Settings\ [your user name]

folder, you may have to use folder options to unhide hidden and system folders to see everything, copy off the files you need to a usb drive.

Once your files are safe you can work on the user profile problem.

NOTE:  the desktop is a bad place to store files, system restore can delete  user created desktop items, always store files in My Documents or create additional folders on the C drive and store them there, you can make shortcuts on the desktop to those files or folders.