# Group Policy Client Service failed; user folders gone

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, group-policy, user-profiles

I have exactly the same problem as described in this post from 2012 ([Can't log in normally, have desktop and user profile issues in Safe Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/426106/cant-log-in-normally-have-desktop-and-user-profile-issues-in-safe-mode)), but there appears to be no final solution to that post, and I have not found a solution on other forums, either.

I have already tried restoring to a previous time, which allowed me to log in to the profile; however, the user folders (Documents, Music, etc.) were still not there.  I looked for the .bak key for the profile in the registry editor, but it did not exist.  Finally, I deleted the user profile, and a folder was created on my desktop which was supposed to contain the files of the user; however, the folder was empty.

I have administrator access using another profile, but am now at a loss as to what else I can try to recover the documents which were in the problem user profile (which was an administrator account).  I have Windows 7 Professional, and had recently created a new administrator profile.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide! Do I just need to send the hard drive to a repair professional who can attempt to recover them?

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problem on windows 10 64x enterprise the solution aside than deleting the profile itself it was deleting the SID key from registry it is located in HKEY_USERS\ by searching for your profile name and finding the SID below it or by navigating to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ [SID]

More info could be found here [Delete profile's SID](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/07/delete-user-profile-domain-joined-windows-pc/)

Comment: You should quote and cite all relevant information from your link.  Your answer by itself should answer the author's question.